# Sequential number thats not primary key for has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have an invoicing rails app and I am trying to add a column that is called `invoice_number` and the table has a primary key of `invoice_id` I want `invoice_number` to be set on save and increment by 1 
So every user should have invoices where the `invoice_number` starts from `1`

The number I want to add is only for auditing purposes and should be private.

I wanted to know what the best way to do something like this would be

```
    after_save :increment_invoice_number

  private
    def increment_invoice_number
     self.invoice_number = current_user.invoice.count + 1
    end
```

I know this block wont work but its kind of what im trying to do.
Does anyone know of a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work... it assumes that you never destroy invoices (otherwise you may end up with duplicate invoice numbers)

```
before_save :increment_invoice_number

private

def increment_invoice_number
 return if persisted?
 self.invoice_number = user.invoices.count + 1
end
```

Note the `return if persisted?` which means you only set the invoice number for a new record, not for an existing one.